# Spark Streaming : How to make spark distribution of RDD's across cluster

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

We have a spark streaming application running on a cluster managed by the yarn ..i see the job is very slow and see uneven distribution

as shown in the picture where i have highlighted one node taking most of rdd's

[image]

From research found that we can repartition or colasace ...but little lost on which one to use ...

Would grealty appreciate if any of the experts in the community will help out as we are new to Spark

Comment: please show your code

Comment: I'm having this exact issue. Please let me know if you get any progress. It's making me mad.

Comment: Yeah, please share your code..